# How can I set unscaled HiDPI mode on VirtualBox command line?

Tags: virtualbox, display, gui, vagrant, macbook-pro-retina

VirtualBox 5 has support for "unscaled HiDPI output" via the machine|settings|display dialog.  However, I can't find a matching modifyvm option in the manual.  How do I set this from the command line?

Bonus questions:

I'm actually trying to make a Vagrant config that will work both on a mac with a retina display and on a Windows box with no HiDPI.  Will setting unscaled HiDPI output screw things up on the Windows box?

I also need to set up Lubuntu to look reasonable on HiDPI since by default it has unreadably tiny fonts.  I know how to change some settings to fix part of the breakage using the GUI, but are there some commands I can put in a provisioning script to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a specific `VBoxManage modifyvm` option because this behavior is GUI-specific but unscaled HiDPI output can be set from the command line with:

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME GUI/HiDPI/UnscaledOutput 1
```

See: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/15425